# How to assign variable to string with hyphens in Python?

Tags: python, environment-variables

There's is very simple. I have a `prob.py` with environment variables:

```
SECRET_KEY = mykey
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypspwd
CONTACT = myemail@me.com
APIKEY_BOT = 11aa11a1-111a-1aa1-11a1-11aaa1a1a111
```

When I try to access this from my Django settings file, I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/src/app/prjbot/prob.py", line 4
APIKEY_BOT= 11aa11a1-111a-1aa1-11a1-11aaa1a1a111
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm assuming that the issue is with the hyphens. I tried adding quotes around the API key, but that didn't work. What am I missing?

I found other stack overflow issues where users want the variable name to include a hyphen, but I didn't find this issue where the var is being defined with a string that includes hyphens.

Comment: _I tried adding quotes around the API key_ That should have worked.  `APIKEY_BOT = "11-aa-11"`

Comment: Those aren't environment variables. They are just regular Python variables.

Comment: Actually, I wonder how the first 3 variable assignments worked and did not raise a syntax error.

Comment: Are you sure this is in a Python file and not a .env file? in a .py file, the email syntax would also be invalid.

Comment: @samthegolden The first two are fine, but you're right about the third one.

Comment: Perhaps all would have gotten errors, but the author is just reading the APIKEY_BOT variable in first and so errors for the other items haven't been raised yet.

Comment: @bones225 The syntax is fine, but unlikely to evaluate the way you expect. `myemail@me.com` would be parsed as "matrix multiplication" of the variable `myemail` and the `com` attribute of the object `me`. I would expect any one of `NameError`, `AttributeError`, or `TypeError` to be raised.

Answer (score 1):

You are using environmental variables incorrectly. Environmental variables are designed to sit outside of your code in a file named `.env`.

You can then setup your Python code to import the variables from the `.env` file.

**.env**

```
SECRET_KEY = mykey
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypspwd
CONTACT = myemail@me.com
APIKEY_BOT = 11aa11a1-111a-1aa1-11a1-11aaa1a1a111
```

**prob.py**

Use [python-decouple](https://github.com/henriquebastos/python-decouple/) to import your variables.

```
from decouple import config

SECRET_KEY         = config('SECRET_KEY')
POSTGRES_PASSWORD  = config('POSTGRES_PASSWORD')
CONTACT            = config('CONTACT')
APIKEY_BOT         = config('APIKEY_BOT')
```